# What `NumberStyles` is used for int.Parse and double.Parse?

Tags: c#, .net

In C#/.NET, what is used for `NumberStyles`, when the methods `Double.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` and `Int32.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` are called?

Documentation ([Double.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=net-5.0), [Int32.Parse](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0)) is not clear about this. The overload `.Parse(ReadOnlySpan<Char>, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` suggests the following:

- Double: `NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint | NumberStyles.AllowExponent | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingSign | NumberStyles.AllowLeadingWhite | NumberStyles.AllowThousands | NumberStyles.AllowTrailingWhite | NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.Integer`
- Int32: `NumberStyles.Integer`

Under the overload `Double.Parse(string, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` there is the following vague and contradicting statement:

> A typical value to specify is `Float` combined with `AllowThousands`.

Can someone clarify this?

**/Update:**
I hat a look at the disassembly and found that `Double.Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` redirects to the latter overload and indeed applies `Float | AllowThousands` for the `NumberStyles` argument.

Comment: How is the documentation not clear? I see that you have linked to the German version. At least in the English version, it tells you exactly which NumberStyles are used in the Remarks section.

Comment: It also makes me wonder why you went to the documentation for the `Parse(ReadOnlySpan<Char>, NumberStyles, IFormatProvider)` overload, when you are asking about the `Parse(string, IFormatProvider)` overload...

Comment: @Sweeper, can you please indicate what the default is then? In the Remarks section I can only see a description of the different `NumberStyles` values, but not *what is used as default if the parameter is omitted*. There is just a vague statement _"A typical value to specify is Float combined with AllowThousands"_ (interestingly this contradicts the default used for the `ReadOnlySpan<>` overload.

Answer (score 1):

The documentation for [`Double.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.double.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Double_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_) says:

> The `s` parameter is interpreted using a combination of the `NumberStyles.Float` and `NumberStyles.AllowThousands` flags.

And for [`Int32.Parse`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.int32.parse?view=net-5.0#System_Int32_Parse_System_String_System_IFormatProvider_):

> The `s` parameter is interpreted using the `NumberStyles.Integer` style.

You can also see that this is indeed the case in the source code of [`Int32.Parse`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Int32.cs,133)

```
    public static int Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider)
    {
        if (s == null) ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.s);
        return Number.ParseInt32(s, NumberStyles.Integer, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
    }
```

and [`Double.Parse`](https://source.dot.net/#System.Private.CoreLib/Double.cs,306)

```
    public static double Parse(string s, IFormatProvider? provider)
    {
        if (s == null) ThrowHelper.ThrowArgumentNullException(ExceptionArgument.s);
        return Number.ParseDouble(s, NumberStyles.Float | NumberStyles.AllowThousands, NumberFormatInfo.GetInstance(provider));
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It allows you to change how strict C# is when processing the input

```
//all work because c# allows you to put thousands separators, decimals, whitespace etc ( , in my culture btw) by default
double.Parse("1234.56");
double.Parse("1,234.56");
double.Parse(" 1,234.56");

//fails because the given flags permit the input to only contain a decimal point. The , will cause "Input not in a correct format" exception
double.Parse("1,234.56", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint);
    
//works because the given flags permit the input to contain a decimal point and thousands sep
double.Parse("1,234.56", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint|NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
    
//fails because input flags don't permit leading whitespace
double.Parse(" 1,234.56", NumberStyles.AllowDecimalPoint|NumberStyles.AllowThousands);
```

and so on